# Performance of custom function while using .apply on Pandas Dataframes

Tags: performance, pandas, vectorization, apply

As the title suggests, I wanted to get a better sense of the the limitations ,in terms of speed, in using a custom function applied to a dataframe. example:

```
df.apply(custom_function)
```

the docs and their related content are (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a bit shifty on the subject simply referring to this feature as making it slower depending on the function used. Since I have no idea how this vectorization takes place - thus rendering the profiling of my function a time consuming-try-and-repeat thing, could someone point to some rule-of-thumb as to what kind of stuff:
1) does not reduce speed
2) greatly slows down the whole process

to be more precise: if, in the function, I save stuff stuff elsewhere, will I get badly damaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the main reason a custom function slows Pandas down is that the built in methods are implemented in Cython (C-Extensions for Python). Anything purely pythonic you will use will be drastically slower than what comes built in. If you manage to use for your needs extensions that are also implemented in Cython, you might get lucky and have relatively nice performance. According to the Pandas docs "... final cythonized solution is around 100 times faster than the pure python" (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html)

In general, I would avoid writing values from inside an apply function. I can't imagine why you'd want to do that. If you need info regarding the returned series, it's probably better to test it in retrospect, after the apply is done.